# Calculating $\tan A$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I was solving this trigonometric problem and I am stuck,

> If, In a $\triangle{ABC}$ $$\sin A=2018\cdot\sin B\cdot\sin C$$
>
> $$\cos A=2018\cdot\cos B\cdot\cos C$$
>   then, $\tan A$ equals?
>
> 1. Not finite
> 2. $1$
> 3. $0$
> 4. $2018$
> 5. $2019$

**My Attempt:**

I divided both the equations to get, $$\tan A=\tan B\cdot\tan C$$

Also, $$\tan{(B+C)}=\frac{\tan B+\tan C}{1-\tan B\cdot\tan C}$$

$$\tan{(\pi-A)}=\frac{\tan B+\tan C}{1-\tan A}$$

$$-\tan A=\frac{\tan B+\tan C}{1-\tan A}$$

$$\tan^2 A-\tan A=\tan B+\tan C$$

I do not know how to proceed. Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin{A}=2018\cdot\sin{B}\cdot\sin{C}\tag1$$
$$\cos{A}=2018\cdot\cos{B}\cdot\cos{C}\tag 2$$
$$\cos(B+C)=\cos B\cos C-\sin B\sin C\tag3$$
$$\cos(B+C)=\cos(\pi-A)=-\cos A\tag4$$
From $(1),(2)$
$$\sin A-\cos A=2018(\sin{B}\cdot\sin{C}-\cos{B}\cdot\cos{C})$$
By $(3),(4)$
$$\sin A-\cos A=-2018\cos(B+C)=2018\cos A$$
$$\iff\tan A-1=2018\implies\tan A=2019$$